# Redirect .html and .php links to no extensions

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, redirect

I have a [website](http://www.eurobytes.nl/), that i wrote by hand, no CMS, just for learning purposes. A while ago I rewrote my website using more of php and renamed the `.html` files to `.php`.

Ages ago I edited the `.htaccess` added some code that i got online. And what it did was, it doesn't use a `tutorials/article.html` or `tutorials/article.php`but no extensions at all: `tutorials/article`

I found that allot of websites that linked to my articles are still using the `.html` extension.

My question is how do I redirect all the links going to `.php` and `.html` to no extensions at all?

Also: I have social haring buttons on my website, does the redirect to no extensions at all, mean that all the `+1`, `likes`, `tweets` and linkedin are no more?

Comment: Can you show us the rules you already have that you're using for extension less URLs.

Comment: @anubhava, unfortunately, not at this time(Work, bills, HALO) tonight or tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your htaccess. It will remove the .html

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Source: http://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/

Answer (score 0):

Do this with **htaccess**

Something like below, for both url with `.php` & `html` extention

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+([^\?\ ]+)\.(php|html?)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301]
```